# Storing user input into hash RUBY

Tags: ruby, hash

Im trying to store all of User's input into a hash and then loop through the hash and display results.
Input: First name, Last Name, Age, City Visited(user will input multiple cities until they input "exit".

Here's what I got so far..and everything looks good *except being able to separate the cities as multiple Values when multiple cities are entered.*

```
result = ""
print "Enter first name "
first = gets.chomp
print "Enter last name "
last = gets.chomp
print "Enter age "
age = gets.chomp

while TRUE
print "Enter city"
city = gets.chomp
if city == "exit"
  break
end
result = result + " " + city
end

user_data = { first: first, last: last, age: age, city: result}

puts "#{user_data}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use an array for this purpose, like this:

```
cities = []

loop do
  print "Enter city: "
  city = gets.chomp
  if city == "done"
    break
  end
  cities << city
end

user_data = { first: first, last: last, age: age, city: cities}
```

And after that you can make a string representation by joining the elements of the array, for example

```
cities.join(' ')
```